# Why does my question have 2(Now Three) close vote? (What does “TTY” stand for?)

Tags: discussion, support

On my question [What does “TTY” stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for?noredirect=1#comment641395_481906) It two (Now Three) close votes even worse than a down vote!  
As you can see here:
[image]

 I am very sad!  Why whould anyone that is nice close it? There are samlier questions to it. For example [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472175/why-it-is-sudo) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304010/what-does-stand-for) and fannly[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446755/what-does-gu-stand-for) but there are many more!

Comment: `I am very sad! Why whould anyone that is nice close it?` Closing is not about being "nice". It is about the question. While I am not saying I think the question ought to be closed, saying that people are not "nice" because they think your question should be closed, for whatever reason, is silly.

Comment: @Seth yea but there are samlier question to it why arent they being close?

Comment: @Seth that is why I think they are being mean to be is because why aren't those questions has close vote too!

Comment: You don't have the reputation to view close votes on those questions, so you can't tell anyway. Just because you see them on *your* question does not mean that there aren't any on the other questions. Nor does it mean they are being "mean" to you.

Comment: @Seth well I just think it would be nice to comment on the question why they think it should be close!

Comment: It is genrally practice to comment as why the question should be closed - in fact when you use [the close vote thing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Ayj.png) it sometimes automatically adds a comment to say `this should be closed due to blaa blaa` - these can be edited or deleted however. [In this case](http://i.stack.imgur.com/grCpx.png), it appears to being close voted as it is not about Ubuntu - which is odd as it sort of is... (though it can refer to Unix and Linux systems genrally)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three people have voted "Off-topic: This is not about Ubuntu".

Perhaps they think it's too generic but I honestly don't have a problem with it.

- TTY is a term we use *all* over Ask Ubuntu.
- It's a term used throughout the official documentation.
- It's something used in Ubuntu.

Why the hell wouldn't that be on-topic here? Yes, it's also on-topic elsewhere but so what?

Comment: I think it's not because is on topic elsewhere but OP is asking a english language question, which IMO we are not experts.

Comment: I think we should edit the question to be more generic, I.e. "what is a tty" vs " what does tty mean". As Braiam points out, the question is really close to being an English question.

Answer (score 1):

My Answer is not my opinion, it's just answer.

Generally in Ask Ubuntu, The questions should flow about Ubuntu related issues. So if your Question stands for even 1% Ubuntu related then you can ask here. Mention the version of Ubuntu OS you are trying/dealing with this issue.

Next, Votes : See somebody may like your question so UPVOTE and somebody may not so DOWNVOTE. Its up to them. And you absolutely have a right to ask them an explanation about DOWNVOTE. If they are the real dealers then they will give explanation.

If you feel something onto you and your questions, then raise a flag to moderator. They will take care.